# Abel's lemma confusion

Tags: summation, definition

From proof wiki (Abel's Lemma):

> Let $\left \langle {a} \right \rangle$ and $\left \langle {b} \right \rangle$ be sequences in an arbitrary ring $R$.
>
> Let $\displaystyle A_n = \sum_{i \mathop = m}^n {a_i}$ be the partial sum of $\left \langle {a} \right \rangle$ from $m$ to $n$.
>
> Then:$\displaystyle \sum_{i \mathop = m}^n a_i b_i = \sum_{i \mathop = m}^{n-1} A_i \left({b_i - b_{i+1}}\right) + A_n b_n$

What does $A_i$ signify here? From the definition given for $A_n$ I would think that $A_i = \sum_{i \mathop =m}^i a_i = a_i$. Where am I wrong?

Comment: Bound and free variables confused.  Define $\displaystyle A_n = \sum_{k \mathop = m}^n {a_k}$ instead to avoid confusion.

Comment: Note that we have $$A_i =\sum_{j=m}^{i} a_j$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable $i$ in the definition $$A_n = \sum_{i \mathop = m}^n {a_i}$$ is just a "dummy variable", and can be changed without changing the meaning: it's just a placeholder that represents all the indices between $m$ and $n$ that you're plugging in.  In particular, note that the sum doesn't make sense if you replace $n$ with $i$, since $i$ is being used simultaneously as a dummy variable inside the sum and as a parameter outside it.  To make sense of the sum $A_i$, then, you should change the internal variable $i$ to something else like $j$:  $$A_i = \sum_{j \mathop = m}^i {a_j}$$